# AS3 Adding an object from a function into an object in another function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, methods

Library:
host - Host
fileicon - file

Information:
Host is a container, it has a mask and I will use this to have lot's of child objects called files. Later in the code I wish to have a removeChild(Host) so when I activate this, it will remove the Host thus removing all the files too. Clean slate.

The file itself is just an object, i have the rest of the code working fine but whenever it comes to adding these to the host, it just wont work... 
Obviously here you see the Host is actually created in a hostSetup function and the files will be created in the addfiles function but i need to communicate between the two to add the file into the host. 
-Re wrote this to hopefully make it a little more understandable.

(sorry its it confuses you)

```
function hostSetup()
{
    addChild(Host);
    addChild(HostMask);
}
function addFiles()
{
    Host.addChild(file);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's entirely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Where it says Host.addChild(file), this should add a file to the Host, that way later when I choose to delete the host, it will clear all the files i put in it. But I don't know what the link would be, becuase I can't just say Host.addChild or this.Host.addChild. I'm sorry that i'm unclear i'm struggling myself not gonna lie, im new to AS3

Comment: What is `Host`? What is `file`?

Comment: Host is a movieclip [Symbol 203] AS linkage host; file is a movieclip also with as linkage file. When it starts up, nothing is on stage its all made using the code so it will add a host to the stage

Comment: I didn't see your edit, it clarifies a few things +1 for that. Now what is the instance name of this `Host`? What is "Symbol 203"? How are those functions in your question called?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RcpTQ0w.png - Hopefully this image will help, i just need to add a child to the Host from another function, (Thanks for bearing with me here I know I am not that good at explaining)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Host` is local variable in the function `initHost()`. It is unknown outside the function.

To make it available to your other function `addFiles()` you have to declare the variable outside the function.

from this

```
function initHost()
{
    var Host:host = new host();
```

to this

```
var Host:host;
function initHost()
{
    Host = new host();
```

you should then be able to add children to that container:

```
Host.addChild(file);
```

Of course you have to make sure that the function `initHost()` is executed before you do that to ensure that the object exists.

---

By convention, variable names should start wit a small letter and class names (linkage name) should start with a capital letter. I highly recommend following that convention. Ideally your code would look like this:

```
var host:Host;
function initHost()
{
    host = new Host();
```

and

```
host.addChild(...);
```

Comment: This explains a lot! Thanks, i'm glad that you understood it in the end haha! I tried to mark your answer as useful but i'm a too low rank for it to mean anything at the moment, if there's anything I can do that will show for you then let me know!